# Facebook Ads - How can I create a Website Custom Audience based on custom data

Tags: facebook

I changed the 'Custom Audiences pixel code' to send 'custom data' as explained on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/website-custom-audiences/planning

But in Power Editor I can only create Audiences based on the url of the page on my site.

How can I use the custom data to create an Audience ?

Answer (score 1):

You will have the option to segment audiences by events after the custom tag will be fired on your webpage (after one day or so). Then, just go to Create Audience -> Custom Audience -> Website Traffic -> Custom Combination -> Choose Event and voila, you have it.

Comment: Thanks Cornel, I had been waiting for this feature a long time.

It works the same with Power Editor.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best hint I could find for your question so far: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-website-faq#fbpixel

What they suggest is to create an audience and add a rule, like:

```
{
    'or': [
        { 'url': { 'i_contains': 'signup' } },
        { 'event': { 'i_contains': 'SignUp' } }
    ]
}
```

Hence, the question is how create an audience on the fly and include your rule, which they suggest as follows:

```
curl \
-F "name='my_audience'" \
-F "subtype=WEBSITE" \
-F "retention_days=15" \
-F 'rule={"url":{"i_contains":""}}' \
-F "access_token=_____" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/act_<ad account id>/customaudiences"
```

So, the final code would be:

```
curl \
-F "name='my_audience'" \
-F "subtype=WEBSITE" \
-F "retention_days=15" \
-F 'rule={
    'or': [
        { 'url': { 'i_contains': 'signup' } },
        { 'event': { 'i_contains': 'SignUp' } }
    ]
}' \
-F "access_token=_____" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/act_<ad account id>/customaudiences"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks like the right answer if you have access to the 'Facebook Ads API'.

Comment: @MatthieuP. Please note that for using the Facebook Ads API you would require your Facebook App to be whitelisted first. Here's the link to the application form: https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/517221111658494

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-website-faq

> Q: Are Rules solely based on URLs? Can we apply more complex rules for
> sophisticated clients?
>
> A: Via PowerEditor or Ads Manager, rules can
> only be configured based on URL, but there is a new JS feature that
> will enable PMDs and clients to create any custom audience dynamically
> via variables they decide to pass to Facebook.